# Cannot flag duplicate question if it has the identical title

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions

[Why we do not refuel and assemble in orbit? - Space Exploration Meta Stack Exchange](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/why-we-do-not-refuel-and-assemble-in-orbit)

[Why we do not refuel and assemble in orbit? - Space Exploration Meta Stack Exchange](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/why-we-do-not-refuel-and-assemble-in-orbit)

are identical posts.

I tried to flag the second as a duplicate of the first, but couldn't because it claimed: "Your search returned no matches; please try a different search":

[image: > Your search returned no matches; please try a different search]

Comment: I always use the whole url in that search box, in this case `https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1624` and that works for me.

Comment: Unlike ordinary duplicates, one of those should be deleted, there's no point keeping both. It's a result of a bug allowing people to click the submit button twice in a row, and no server side check to prevent the double posting. So this is a "sub bug" - a bug which is direct result of another bug.

Comment: actually both need to be gone. They're both on meta.

Comment: So while it may be a real bug, the proper action isn't a dupe closure. Its a normal closure/deletion

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Where on Meta?  Meta SE?

Comment: Look closer. They asked a main site question on  that site's meta. Twice

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah, you're right.

Comment: This seems to be the same bug I found many years ago. It is not related to the fact that the title is the same but rather because neither question has been answered. You can see this is the case by editing the title of one of the questions.